# jQuery Extract selector array index

Tags: jquery

I wanted to extract the array index of the selected input text from data table row

```js
(function($) {
  $('table tbody').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
 
    var a = $(tr).find('input.dataform').attr('name');
    alert(a);
  });

})
```

```html
 <table>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="dataform[1][firstname]" class="dataform"/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="dataform[2][firstname]" class="dataform"/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Suppose button in first row fired; var a return dataform[1][firstname] and that is correct. However I lso wanted to extract the input name array index which is 1

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code bellow work, or you can try add a data-idx="1" on button and you add also a data-idx="1" on closest input, so you can get fast with `$('input[data-idx="'+$(this).attr('data-idx')+'"]').attr('name');`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent().find('tr');
    $(tr).hide();
    var a = $(this).parent().parent().find('input.dataform').attr('name');
    alert(a);
  });
});
```

```html
 <table>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="dataform[1][firstname]" class="dataform"/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="dataform[2][firstname]" class="dataform"/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn">Go</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Perfect. The custom attribute was a go mate! Thanks